# How can I write an Arabic word using ABNtex2 with package french and Brazil babel

Tags: babel, polyglossia, arabic, french, abntex2

When I introduce the `polyglossia` package I have the message

> Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}

Comment: What is your complete LaTeX code, please? Can you edit your question, please?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the languages as class options:

```
\documentclass[french,brazilian,bidi=default]{abntex2}

\babelprovide{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\languagename

\foreignlanguage{arabic}{واحد} two \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ثلاثة} four

\selectlanguage{french}

\languagename

\end{document}
```

This should work with both `xetex` and `luatex`.

Comment: thainks but i have this message

Comment: Package fontspec Error: The font "FreeSerif" cannot be found. ^^I\foreignlanguage{arabic}{واحد}

Comment: and i use the classe ICMC: \documentclass[doutorado,pre-defesa,french,brazilian,bidi=default]{packages/icmc}

Comment: Why did you mention ABNtex2, then? Please, edit your question to add a minimal example. As to FreeSerif, it is included in TeXLive.